# Is there any possible way to create backup of Windows XP like windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-backup

I want to know is there any way to create the backup of Windows XP like in Windows 7? As in windows & there is a option for a schedule backup and it creates an image of backup on external source and we can easily get back data from there through recovery option. So is it possible in windows XP?

Comment: AFAIK, it isn't possible with built-in tools, but there is software that you can pay for...

Comment: Which is that can you tell me @Zoredache?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in NTBACKUP but it pales in comparison to the backup technology offered in 7 and Vista. There are a number of third party options that will do what you are looking for.

http://us.norton.com/ghost/

http://www.acronis.com/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You want to use NTBACKUP. You can read all about [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntbackup_command.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: You cannot restore files from the command line using the ntbackup command. What does it mean there I could not get?

Comment: Your question wasn't about restoring files from the command line from a previously taken backup. Generally (I think we all hope) that the need to do a restore from a backup is an exceptional condition. If you find yourself doing this on a regular basis (such that you want to automate the process with a batch file, for instance), there may be another problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I think you didn't read it carefully sir I've mentioned that in last line of my question.

Comment: Sorry. Rereading the last bit of your question, "is a option for a schedule backup and it creates an image of backup on external source and we can easily get back data from there through recovery option. So is it possible in windows XP?" you don't mention wanting/needing to do this via the command line, or on a regular basis.